# Choosing at least 2 red balls from the urn

Tags: probability

There are 2 blue balls and 4 red balls in the urn.What is the probability of the choosing at least 2 red balls from the urn when the 4 balls are chosen with replacement ? Here's what I've tried :

( C(4,2).C(2,2) + C(4,3).C(2,1) + C(4,4) ) /  C(6,4)

But it results 1 which doesn't make sense.Is the problem relevant with the replacement part , can't I use the combination if there's replacement in the question ?

Comment: "*What is the probability of choosing at least two red balls from the urn with replacement?*"  Since I'm not able to touch the urn, I can't pull any balls from it, much less at least two red balls.  If I draw only one ball from the urn, I still cannot successfully draw two red balls.  You are missing a very crucial part of the problem statement.  How many balls are we drawing?

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh I am sorry , we are choosing 4 balls from the urn i'm editing now

Comment: It sounds as though you are asking for the probability that at least two of the balls you draw with replacement are red **when you draw four balls** with replacement.  In that case, no, you may not use the combinations approach like you did above.  That approach is used very specifically for when the balls are taken *without* replacement.  You should instead be using the binomial distribution.  This is essentially the same as asking for the probability of flipping at least two heads out of four flips with an unfairly weighted coin.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\color{red}{ \frac{2}{3}}+\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{3}}\right)^4=\underbrace{\left(\color{red}{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)^4+4 \left(\color{red}{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)^3\left(\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{3}}\right)+6\left(\color{red}{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)^2\left(\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{3}}\right)^2}_{P(\color{red}{2+})=\frac{72}{81}=\frac{8}{9}}+4\left(\color{red}{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)\left(\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{3}}\right)^3+\left(\color{blue}{ \frac{1}{3}}\right)^4
\end{eqnarray*}
Edit:
Note that the above equation is equal to $1$ and lists all of the possible outcomes. The expanded terms on the RHS correspond to $4,3,2,1,0$ red balls respectively. We require the first three terms.

Comment: It looks well but could you explain the main idea here ?

Comment: Are you familiar with binomial distribution? There are $4\choose{4}$ ways to select 4 red balls, $4\choose{1}$ way to choose 3 red balls and 1 blue ball, $4\choose{2}$ $= 6$ ways to select 2 red balls and 2 blue balls, etc.

Comment: I'll look at it , thanks for kind advice

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint:
Try the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Use successes as drawing a red and failures as drawing a blue.
This should be calculated using 2, 3, and 4 successes.

Comment: Thanks for kind advice